# Can `while (i != 0 && (a[i].p != 0 || a[i].q != 0));` do anything except freezing?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm reading someone else's C++ code, and I'm perplexed about a line with the following structure:

```
while (i != 0 && (a[i].p != 0 || a[i].q != 0));
```

where

- `i` is an unsigned integer index
- `a` is an array with `struct`s that have integer members `p` and `q`.

Note that the body of the while loop is empty (semicolon). Also note that there are no increment / decrement operators or any assignments inside of the condition.

I don't understand how this line could possibly ever do anything. There seem to be only two cases:

1. The condition is not satisfied, and the loop is exited immediately.
2. The condition is satisfied, the loop becomes infinite, the program freezes forever.

Is there *any* imaginable context in which this line would make sense, i.e. do something nontrivial, and also not freeze forever?

Some theoretically imaginable, but unlikely "solution attempts":

- Some of the `!=`, `[]`, `&&`, `||` operators have been overridden in some strange unexpected way
- The loop is actually a "busy wait" loop, and either `i` or contents of `a` are changed from another thread, and then eventually "leak", because the memory model does not guarantee that writes in another thread will not become visible, even without any proper synchronization. But that would seem extremely ugly, so forgive me that I thought of this possibility.

Are there any contexts in which this line might become meaningful, or is this just some buggy code, a condition that is never satisfied, and should be refactored into an `assert` instead?

Comment: "*The condition is satisfied, the loop becomes infinite, the program freezes forever."* Infinite loops that don't do anything significant are undefined behavior. They don't necessarily loop forever. See [progress guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Forward_progress).

Comment: Are you sure  all of the variables are integers and not `atomic`s?

Comment: What is `i` initialised to? What happens if `i` is some memory-mapped variable?

Comment: It's not possible to override the built-in operators for built-in types, and unsynchronized shared access to an `int` is undefined behavior. So both of your theories must be incorrect (or the code contains an error).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Alright, maybe they don't "loop forever", because sooner or later the machine falls apart. But that's not much more useful than looping forever. I assume that the one who wrote this line wanted to achieve something meaningful, I just don't understand what it is.

Comment: "*... because sooner or later the machine falls apart.*" No, because the compiler might just remove that loop. If you want our help in understanding the code, show the whole code, not just random snippets.

Comment: @Indestruktible I mean that it's UB, so it might not loop at all. If you have `while(true);` or an equally provable infinite loop that violates forward progress, the compiler can just eliminate that code, that branch or that entire function or do anything else. I don't mean that it won't physically run forever. I mean the loop might not exist at all. That code can't be used to express the desire to freeze a thread. It only expresses that the condition can be safely assumed by the compiler to be `false`. Either it's `false` or you have UB and the compiler can still assume it's `false`.

Comment: Is there a related statement after the `while` loop, and the `;` is a typo?

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, like in the question, `while(true);` is equivalent to `while(true) {}`.

Comment: @melpomene Sorry, I understand that it's not a "minimal verifiable example". My problem is exactly that: I cannot think of any minimal example where this line would have any meaning. It seems that in every possible contexts, it either does nothing, or it's UB, as François Andrieux said. If I had to "minimize" this code into a minimal example, I'd just remove the loop, and then I'd be left with an empty code snippet.

Comment: I'm not asking for a minimal example, I'm asking for the full original code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: How can you say no? The OP has not shown us the code after the `while` loop. So how would you have that information? The next line in the file could be a statement that was intended to be the body of the `while` loop, and the `;` was added to the `while` line by mistake.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The `;` means there is no loop body. Edit : From the question, it explicitly says : *"Note that the body of the while loop is empty (semicolon)."* It's not a typo.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Have you never seen code with that kind of typo / bug?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I did not ask about the loop body. I asked about the statements **after** the `while` loop, not in it in its current form.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's not a typo in the question, but it may be a typo in the code.

Comment: Ok, sorry everyone. False alarm. The problem was just indentation style I'm not used to. There is hundred miles long `do { ... }` block above the `while` condition, and then a line break. That was silly. Sorry about that. Looks like "trivial typo", or just irrelevant code indentation issue.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, I see. I agree that this may be what happened. I agree that we can't tell either way. I thought the comment that started this was asking about my own comment instead of the question. Sorry.

Comment: @Indestruktible Hehe I always get caught out by `do`/`while`. Sounds like that function could use a bit of splitting up!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, "splitting up" is exactly what I'm currently attempting to do. Thanks. Why would anyone close the `}` of a `do { } while`, then cynically add a line break, then write down the `while` condition, that's just mean. Now I feel like a complete fool. Thanks everyone for helpful suggestions anyway.

Comment: @Indestruktible You should find them, and kill them.

Answer (score 2):

This is bad code no matter how you look at it.

There are two possible choices that I can see:

1. The programmer wrote a bug.
2. It's multi-threaded, and one of the values is going to change from another thread, and the programmer didn't do proper thread synchronization.

Your suggestion about weird operator overloading is possible, but wow! That would really be a stretch (and horrible, horrible coding practice, as none of the operators used should ever be written with side effects).

My guess: someone forgot to increment i.

Comment: "Forgot to increment i" doesn't make much sense with `i != 0`.

Comment: The suggestion about operator overloading is not possible. You can't overload an operator with just built-in types.

Comment: Perhaps that should be decrement i then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @JosephLarson, but I'm afraid the explanation is much more mundane: I simply missed that it's the end of a very long and strangely indented `do { ... } while();`, with too many line breaks between the closing `}` and the problematic `while`. I'd also have expected something like `i--` somewhere. Not sure what to do with the question now, it probably should be closed & deleted as a "trivial typographical mistake".

Comment: Sometimes asking other programmers your question helps you figure it out. I don't know how many times I've solved my own problems by asking someone else to look at the code with me.

Comment: Rubber ducky\ you're the one.\ You make coding\ lots of fun.